# Play! - unique model field

Tags: java, validation, playframework

How can I make my model class fields unique? Eg. if login is already taken, I'd like to display proper message for the user. I have to write my own validation check and use it, or JPA `@UniqueConstraint` can be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done it this way:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Basic(optional=false) @Column(unique=true) public String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        create();
    }

    /** used in registration to find name clash */
    public static User findByName(String name) {
        return find("name", name).first();
    }

}
```

and then in the controller you do something like:

```
public static void register(@Required String name) {
    if(User.findByName(name)!=null) {
        Validation.addError("name", "this name is not available");
    }
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        validation.keep();
        params.flash();
        flash.error("Please correct the form data.");
        signup(); // whatever your GET action was
    }

    User user = new User(name);
    login(); // whatever your success action is
}
```

you could do it without the User.findByName() check and you would get a ConstrainViolationException but which is of course not very user friendly. You could also just try/catch that exception. I prefer it both ways, being user friendly and consistent in the database.

Comment: I was also thinking about catching the exception, but this is little bit "untidy" I think. I already did something like what you proposed, but I'm still missing uniqueness in model, so I'll add that to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You must write your own check. See http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~opensource21/+junk/permsec/files/head:/app/de/ppi/util/validation/
I wrote it a few month ago, unfortunately I don't have time for play at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this by overriding the create method in my crud controllers like so. Calling a custom validateUniqueFields method just before the validaiton.hasErrors() method. I can then return valid errors for my unique fields.

```
public static void create() throws Exception 
{
    ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
    notFoundIfNull(type);
    Constructor<?> constructor = type.entityClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Model object = (Model) constructor.newInstance();
    Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "object", object);
    validation.valid(object);
    validateUniqueFields(object);
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        renderArgs.put("error", play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.hasErrors"));
        try {
            render(request.controller.replace(".", "/") + "/blank.html", type, object);
        } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
            render("CRUD/blank.html", type, object);
        }
    }
    object._save();
    flash.success(play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.created", type.modelName));
    if (params.get("_save") != null) {
        redirect(request.controller + ".list");
    }
    if (params.get("_saveAndAddAnother") != null) {
        redirect(request.controller + ".blank");
    }
    redirect(request.controller + ".show", object._key());
}

private static void validateUniqueFields(Model object) {
    String value = ((CastModelHere)object).identifier;
    String ident = "identifier";
    if( TUCharacterTypeIdentifier.find(ident, value).first() != null )
    {
        validation.addError("object." + ident, ident + " already taken");
    }
}
```