# Making attributes in my persistent model unique

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

In the play framework on my models how can I make a certain field a key, as in it must be unique and not repeated. I am using JPA/Hibernate.

For instance if I have a `user_account_tbl` I do not want to be able to add in another user of the same name. Every users name must be unique.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since play uses hibernate under the hood, you can use any of the options available on hibernate.

You can either annotate the attribute with `@Column(unique=true)`

or the class with (this is the only option for unique keys on multiple columns)

```
@Table(name="table",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"column1", "column2"})}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a check in validation, you must wrote your own check as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179598/play-unique-model-field/6186238#6186238).